# How to get screen size?

Tags: android

How to get screen size (in pixels)? I used

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
Point size = new Point(); 
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x; 
int height = size.y;`
```

but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: I'm curious, does ``display.getWidth()`` & ``getHeight()`` return different values than ``display.getSize(Point)`` as OP had tried?

Comment: actually getsize is not available in lower api version ..@harism.. but I think this is not the case here .. :?

Comment: I see, should have read the documentation more closely.

Answer (score 0):

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();     
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```